# How to make an input an answer to 3 different randoms

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple quiz program. But `how do I get the input to be the same as the answer` on the code where the user answers the question?

```
 import random

 print("what is your name \n")
 name=input()
 print("hello",name,"you will be asked 10 math questions goodluck")
 for i in range(10):
   op=["+","-","*"]
   num1=random.randint(0,10)
   num2=random.randint(0,12)
   operation=random.choice(op)
   eval(str(num1)+operation+str(num2)) 

   print(num1,operation,num2)

   while True:
     try:
        user= int(input())
        if user=answer:
           print("correct")
     except:
        print("invaild")
```

Comment: why not store `eval(str(num1)+operation+str(num2))` in `answer`? Also -- exception handling seems pointless for a simple `if...else` logic.

Comment: In your if statement, `user=answer` is an assignment, not a test - you want `user == answer`. Also - standard indentation for Python is 4 spaces.

Comment: i only used the excpention handling to catch the errors so if the user types the a letter or nothing it wont end the program instead it will just say its an invaild answer but thx for the answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is a mathematical operator classed as an interger in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829504/is-a-mathematical-operator-classed-as-an-interger-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `eval`, fix indendtation, address comments and you will get something like this.

```
import random
import operator

operators = {'+': operator.add,
             '-': operator.sub,
             '*': operator.mul}


print("What is your name?")
name = input()

print("Hello {name} you will be asked 10 math questions, good luck.".format(name=name))

for _ in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 12)

    operator = random.choice(operators.keys())
    answer = operators[operator](num1, num2)

    print("{n1} {op} {n2} = ?".format(n1=num1, op=operator, n2=num2))

    try:
        user_input = int(input())
        if user_input == answer:
            print("Correct")
        else:
            print("Invaild")
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number!')
```